# Pandas read_csv. Using '^A' as a delimeter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file where the field separators are `^A` characters. When I try

```
df = pd.read_csv(p_file, sep='^A')
```

The file looks as follows:

```
0J0NrQDHHx^A989.0^A1
0J0NrQDHHx^A1204.0^A1
0U0NrQDHHx^A1654.0^A1
0N0NrQDHHx^A1679.0^A3
...
```

However, when I run the command above, I get everything in one column. Why?

Comment: You need to escape the '^' character using a '\' `pd.read_csv(p_file, sep=r'\^A')`

Answer (score 4):

Use `sep='\^A`:

```
pd.read_csv(p_file, sep='\^A')
```

Reason is that `sep` also accepts regular expressions, and `^` has a special meaning in regular expressions, so the `\` is used to escape this.